# Tab multiple lines

Tags: whitespace, tab-characters

I have my tab set to 4 spaces with `:set tabstop=4`.

Now I want to highlight multiple lines and tab them, or indent all them 4 spaces. If I highlight the lines and do `>`, it seems to indent them more than 4 spaces.

How can I simply indent multiple lines a given number of spaces?

Comment: Yup. Question isn't the same, but the info in that answer helped answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
:set shiftwidth=4
```

which will cause `>` to result in a 4-space indent.